# reading a text file into matlab

Tags: matlab, text-files

I keep trying to read a text file into matlab.
A sample of the text file is as shown below:
Sequence,rank,discipline,sincephd,service,sex,salary
1,Prof,B,19,18,Male,139750
2,Prof,B,20,16,Male,173200
3,AsstProf,B,4,3,Male,79750

My code is as shown:

```
clc
clear all
DELIMITER = ',';
HEADERLINES = 1;
% Import the file
newData1 = importdata('afifi.txt', DELIMITER, HEADERLINES);
% Create new variables in the base workspace from those fields.
vars = fieldnames(newData1);
for i = 1:length(vars)
    assignin('base', vars{i}, newData1.(vars{i}));
end
```

For some reason it will not read the last column properly. It only reads the first value in the first row, then does not read the rest of the last column. Anyone please tell me how to fix this!

Comment: The file is imported correctly, `newData1` has two fields: `data` and `textdata`, the first has the salary column and the latter the rest of the fields. How would you like the data imported? Take a look at [textscan](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) instead.

Comment: I would like them all to be in one variable. Why is it divided into data and textdata? I mean why dont the values 173200 and 79750 appear?

Comment: There is also different [Ways to Import Text Files](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/ways-to-import-text-files.html) in Matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rename `afifi.txt` to `afifi.csv`, you can do this,

```
[num, txt, all] = xlsread('afifi.csv');
```

And get everything in `all`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `readtable` to easily import a textfile with mixed data. The line would be as follows:

```
readtable('afifi.txt','Delimiter',DELIMITER,'ReadVariableNames',true);
```

After you can replace `fieldnames(newData1)` with `newData1.Properties.VariableNames` to get the columnnames. Put together, the code from your question works as desired:

```
clc
clear all
DELIMITER = ',';
% Import the file
newData1 = readtable('afifi.txt','Delimiter',DELIMITER,'ReadVariableNames',true);
% Create new variables in the base workspace from those fields.
vars = newData1.Properties.VariableNames;
for i = 1:length(vars)
    assignin('base', vars{i}, newData1.(vars{i}));
end
```